# Errors in List deleting

Tags: c#, list, oop, linked-list, binaryfiles

I have created a list and a binary file to store data. Now I try to remove from list but it's not working, why?

Errors showing :

> Error  2   : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'XYZ_System.Log' to 'System.Predicate'    E:\Degree Assignment\Application development-semester 1\XYZ_System\XYZ_System\RegisterUser.cs   239 32  XYZ_System
>
> Error1 :The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.RemoveAll(System.Predicate)' has some invalid arguments  E:\Degree Assignment\Application development-semester 1\XYZ_System\XYZ_System\RegisterUser.cs   239 17  XYZ_System

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Log lg = new Log();
           // lg.Username = this.textBox1.Text;
            //lg.Password = this.textBox2.Text;
           // lg.Name = this.txtname.Text;
           // lg.Contact = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtContact_no.Text); ;
           // lg.Email = this.txtEmail_Address.Text;

            Stream stream = File.Open("Login.bin", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            list = (List<Log>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();

            list.RemoveAll(lg);

           // dtvregister.DataSource = list;

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected details has been deleted !", "Success");
                Reset();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should ask *new* questions instead of changing your question radically (and invalidating any useful answers).

Comment: Just rename either `List<Log> list` or `foreach (DataGridViewRow list...)`

Comment: #crashmstr. don't misunderstand.i'm new user here.. so here after it won't happen. thank you

Comment: You can't radically change a question once it has an answer. I've rolled back the question so it's back to it was at the point it was answered. If you need to, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.RemoveAll()` required a function (`Predicate<T>`) that returns a boolean that will be called per item, if the item should be removed. 
This is a definite example:

```
private bool ValidateItem(Log lg)
{
    if(lg.Name == "John")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

list.RemoveAll(ValidateItem);
```

But with lambda expressions, this does the same: `list.RemoveAll(lg => lg.Name == "John");`

In your situation this can be used: `list.RemoveAll(lg => true);`, but you'd better use **`list.Clear();`** instead.

Comment: then how can i delete the file contents.. any more solution .. and code?..thank you

Comment: You could delete the file or just serialize an empty `List<Log>` to the file.

Comment: Not success answer

Comment: The edited part is a completely other question. You don't use the `RemoveAll()` or `Clear()` anymore.

Comment: You should load the file ones. Add/Modify/Delete items in the list. When ready, save the modified list to disk.